# How do I enforce username and password on token generation or is it bad practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have started a simple web api and added token generation to it using jwt. However I used in app accounts for the user store this is my function for setting up the token. Its showing up in swagger fine but what I dont get is how to I enforce the username and password to be entered when the request for token is made. Or is that bad practise.

This is my class when I generate the security token.

```
public JwtService(IConfiguration config)
{
        var test = config;
          _secret = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("SecretKey").Value;

        _expDate = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("expirationInMinutes").Value;
}

    public string GenerateSecurityToken(string email)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email)
        })
        ,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(double.Parse(_expDate)),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    }
}

 public static IServiceCollection AddTokenAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
         var secret = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("SecretKey").Value;
        var keySecret = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(secret);

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keySecret.ToString());
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                // ValidIssuer = "localhost",
                //ValidAudience = "localhost"
            };
        });

        return services;
     }
```

Swagger Gen Code

```
  services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
  {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "App Manager - Running Buddies", Version = "v1" });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
            });
    });
```

Swagger Ui Test

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to pass username/password in a model using [HTTP POST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1#examine-the-posttodoitem-create-method).
Be sure to only issue a token when the login request is valid, i.e. after you have successfully authenticated the user.
See [Securing ASP.NET Core 2.0 Applications with JWTs](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/)
 for further details.

Edit: To perform a login using Identity you could use [SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_PasswordSignInAsync_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) or to just check the credentials [SignInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.checkpasswordsigninasync). See the [samples](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ff773bd843924e73de1d1d0156b1839335ec391e/src/Identity/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L60) for an example:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // generate the token
}
```

Comment: How would i validate against asp.net identity as I am using in app store for my credentials saved in a sql database. While that guide is 2.0 I have see a few things i could use I did state i was using .net 3.1

Comment: I added an example. The relevant concepts are not that different between 2 and 3.1, I think you can use the tutorial to extract the missing pieces for your solution.